# Send sms broadcasts not received

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I have to send sms and do some action upon delivery, I use broadcast pending intent to broadcast the status as follows.

```
BroadcastReceiver smsStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();}
};

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        mBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(smsStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SENT));
        mBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(smsStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_DELIVERED));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Utils.sendSMS(MainActivity.this, "123456", "test", ACTION_SENT, ACTION_DELIVERED);
            }
        });
    }
```

in the Utils

```
public static void sendSMS(Activity activity, String destination, String text, String sentAction, String deliveryAction) {    
        PendingIntent sentPI = null;
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = null;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sentAction)) {
            sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, new Intent(sentAction), 0);
        }
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(deliveryAction)) {
            deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 500, new Intent(deliveryAction), 0);
        }
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(destination, null, text, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
```

the onReceive() is never called though the sms is sent successfully, couldn't find anything not straightforward in the documentation.
Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You need to register your Receiver on a `Context`, not on `LocalBroadcastManager`. Remove `mBroadcastManager.` from the beginning of both of those lines. Note that you might not get the `ACTION_DELIVERED` broadcast at all, if your network doesn't support delivery reports.

Comment: that's what happen when you depend on your utilities for long time :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your BroadcastReceiver in Manifest class ?

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

When sending an SMS using `sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);`, you can provide a pending intent (`sentPI`) to be notified when it is received.

`If not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is delivered to the recipient. The raw pdu of the status report is in the extended data ("pdu").`

You can provide a BroadcastReceiver as a PendingIntent:

```
Intent intentWithData = new Intent(context, SMSDeliveredBroadcastReceiver.class);
intentWithData.putExtra("number",number);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 7, intentWithData, 0);
```